# how do i stop an ever-going rotation when image comes in the upright position in c++

Tags: c++, rotation, box2d, division

I am using box2d engine in c++ and I let some images float freely on the screen. The wander but they also rotate (spin) endlessly around their centre of mass - as if they are in space.

Once in a while, a trigger is set and I want to assume command of the spinning to bring it to a stop. Also I do not want to do that immediately but rather continue the rotation until the image is in the upright position.

Now here is the catch, the box2d physics engine keeps track of the total rotational distance that has been spinned around. That is if the image (for example) has spinned 5 times , the `getRotation()` member function will return a value (in rads) between `10*pi < value < 12*pi` and not a value between `0 < value < 2*pi` .

However, I do not want to unwind all the logged rotations , just stop at the nearest 2*PI multiple. As such, some `modulus (%)` operation should be in order. I can not use `%` because the denominator of this division should be `pi` (i.e not an integer). 
I looked into `fmodf` but I was not able to get the expected result:

```
if(( abs( fmodf(box2dObj.getRotation() , 2*pi) ) == 0 ) ||
   ( abs( box2dObj.getRotation() < STEP ) )
     box2dObj.setRotation( 0 ) ; //remain at 0
else if ( fmodf(box2dObj.getRotation() , pi) ) > 0 )
     box2dObj.setRotation( --box2dObj.getRotation() ) ; //decrease towards 0 if 0 < x < pi
else if ( fmodf(box2dObj.getRotation() , pi) ) < 0 )
     box2dObj.setRotation( ++box2dObj.getRotation() ) ; //increase towards 0 if pi < x < 2*pi
```

STEP is defined as the increment / decrement step size . here is it one (but I have tried with much smaller increment / decrement step sizes, not just `++` and `--` which default to a step of 1).

would become zero even at times when the image was not in the upright position.

what can I do to find when the rotation is at a multiple of `2*pi` ?

Comment: 10*pi < 12*pi is same as 0*pi < 2*pi.

Comment: No. It does not reach zero. it has to unwind 5 times to get to zero (and then stay there). I do not want it to unwind 5 times ...

Comment: From your question what i understand is you want getRotation to return 2*pi but not 12*pi

Comment: which exactly another way of saying I want to know the multiples of `2*PI`

Comment: Can you give an example of rotation for which that function returns zero? Is that angle very close to upright but not exactly? How do you compare the return value to zero?

Comment: Doesnt it work when you take away 10*pi from the returned value

Comment: @user3033613, that works only if the image has spinned 5 times. I believe that number is just an example and that the comparison is supposed to work for any rotation.

Comment: @user2079303 unfortunately, I can not get an output at the moment - i am away from that computer. I update the question abit to include exaclty the if () clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you probably meant `abs( box2dObj.getRotation() ) < STEP` instead of `abs( box2dObj.getRotation() < STEP )` because it doesn't make sense to take absolute value of a bool. In it's current form, the condition would always be true for all negative rotations.

Secondly, you compare a floating point value with equality: `abs( fmodf(box2dObj.getRotation() , 2*pi) ) == 0 )`. That isn't going to work well because floating point values are not exact and their operations have numerical errors. `++box2dObj.getRotation()` might never (likely not within even a lot of iterations) reach a value that is exactly or even near 0 (mod 2*pi).

Thirdly, you have no condition for the case `fmod(r, pi) == 0 && fmod(r, 2*pi) != 0 && r > STEP`, where r is the rotation. In this case the object will not be rotated further nor set upright. This isn't very likely case unless `STEP` is a fraction of `pi` though.

Also, 1 radians is quite a large value for `STEP` in my opinion, but suit yourself.

What you probably want is (I haven't tested this code):

```
if( fmod(abs(box2dObj.getRotation()), 2*pi) < STEP )
    box2dObj.setRotation( 0 )
else if( box2dObj.getRotation() > 0 )
    box2dObj.setRotation( box2dObj.getRotation() + STEP );
else
    box2dObj.setRotation( box2dObj.getRotation() - STEP );
```

This code should test if an object has a rotation that is at most a `STEP` away from a full rotation and in that case sets it to zero. Otherwise the code assumes that objects with positive rotation are rotating in positive direction and vice versa.

> what can I do to find when the rotation is at a multiple of 2*pi ?

You were pretty close. As you can see from my code, I prefer to take the absolute value before `fmod`. This is because there are 3 different ways the modulo operation can behave with negative values (truncated, floored and euclidean) and I find it hard to remember which method is used in which standard / platform.

Then there is the equality problem. You must never test floating points values with equality (except in exceptional cases). Instead, if you want to know if a value - in this case `fmod(abs(box2dObj.getRotation(), 2*pi)` - is close to zero, you must test whether the value is within some margin of error. Since the value always changes by no less than `STEP`, it is an appropriate choice for error margin. This assures that object cannot rotate over the upright position without being caught by the test. In some other case, you might want to use much smaller margin to test equality, but it's rarely correct to test against exact value without some error margin.